# Laravel: supported way to change framework/app folder location?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm just starting to play around with Laravel and noticed in the docs it said they recommend you move your app files outside the document root, with just the content of `/public` being accessible.  Ok, fine, so I've done that.  However, looking in `/public/index.php` it is hard-coded to point up one directory to the `/bootstrap` directory.  Since I've moved the framework code elsewhere, I modified the file slightly to:

```
$app_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../securefiles/myApp/';
...
require $app_path.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
... etc ...
```

Is this the expected practice?  This file needs to be set up correctly before Laravel even loads, so I don't imagine I can configure Laravel itself to know where it's stored relative to `/public/index.php`.  I'm just curious though if there's another, better, more appropriate method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No thats not what they mean. They mean that you need to point the virtualhost to use `public` as the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` leaving the rest of the structure intact. So you would see something like this:

```
projectname/
  app/
  bootstrap/
  public/
```

And then the apache/nginx/lighthttpd virtualhost configuration would set the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to `/path/to/projectname/public`. So there would be no need to change anything really other than your server configuration. That is typically how its done. Apache example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/projectname/public"
    ServerName yoursite.com
    ServerAlias www.yoursite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Marked as correct as it does answer the problem for others who may be in a similar situation. However, I have dozens of apps - each in their own subdirectory, so creating a VH for each app is impractical.  Since my situation isn't explicitly described or accounted for in the docs, can I assume there isn't really an official way to do what I want?

Comment: @Pickle: I make vhost for every application that way they are self-contained. If they are running off the exact same domain or what have you then they should really be modules within a single application IMO. If you are trying to share the same Framework base you could use the include path or something. Also, what you did should technically work i think, its just not the common way to set it up.

Comment: hello @prodigitalson how can we achieve this on a shared hosting where you don't have access to apache configuration.Since the application I am working on is going to be hosted on a shared hosting. What is the work around to hide the code form public access. I have searched on the but didn't find any proper way to do this.

Comment: Any host should give you access to the filesystem outside the web root. At that point its just a matter of figuring out what folder is the webroot by convention, then you can ssh in to the server and create a symlink from your `public` folder to the name the hosting company's set up requires. If your hosting company (even shared hosting) doesnt give you SSH access then you shouldnt use them, because there are plenty that do.